# Change the icon to a marker in Leaflet.Editable

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet.Editable to add markers with different properties to a map.
Like: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable/blob/master/example/index.html
How to customize the icon of the marker or color of the path according to the used tools?

Comment: I can't pass options for the function that creates the marker
Now I use: `map.editTools.startMarker.call(map.editTools);`

This does not work: `map.editTools.startMarker.call(map.editTools, {title:'test'});`

Answer (score 2):

Ok,
I found the solution in Function.prototype.call ().
`map.editTools.startMarker.call(map.editTools, map.editTools, {title:'test'});`